# How do I get the first addeventlistener to work?

Tags: addeventlistener

The other 2 tab triggers work fine but I can't get the first one to work.
The first tab is set to the original text, but when I click on the other 2 I can't get the first tab button to work anymore. If I set it to one of the other text then it works but it won't point back to the original.

What am I missing?

```
<body>
<div class="page_container">
<div class="tab_full_container">
<div class="tab_triggers">
    <div class="trigger1 trigger"><a href="#">01 Cool Stuff</a></div>
    <div class="trigger2 trigger"><a href="#">02 Cool Items</a></div>
    <div class="trigger3 trigger"><a href="#">03 Cool Puppies</a></div>


</div>
<div class="tab_text">
<h1>Cool header 1
</h1>
<p class="text_main">xiosixo xoix oix xoi xoi xio xo xiox oixi xoix oix xio xio xoixx xoix oi xoi oxi iox xo xiox ox ox io </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab_text2" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Cool header2</h1>
    <p class="text_main">xiosixo xoix oix xoi xoi xio xo xiox oixi xoix oix xio xio xoixx xoix oi xoi oxi iox xo xiox ox ox io </p>
</div>

<div class="tab_text3" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Cool header3</h1>
    <p class="text_main">xiosixo xoix oix xoi xoi xio xo xiox oixi xoix oix xio xio xoixx xoix oi xoi oxi iox xo xiox ox ox io </p>
</div>
</div>

    <script src="./tabs.js"></script>
    
</body>

<script>

// individual triggers
const t1 = document.querySelector('.trigger1');
const t2 = document.querySelector('.trigger2');
const t3 = document.querySelector('.trigger3');

// text container
const tt1 = document.querySelector('.tab_text');
const tt2 = document.querySelector('.tab_text2');
const tt3 = document.querySelector('.tab_text3');


t1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    tt1.innerHTML = tt1.innerHTML;
})

t2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    tt1.innerHTML = tt2.innerHTML;
})

t3.addEventListener('click', function () {
    tt1.innerHTML = tt3.innerHTML;
})

</script>
```

Comment: `t1` doesn't do anything. Or rather said, it takes what is at the time of execution within the HTML of tt1, and put it in tt1. 
If you want the original value to be set after changing the content of `tt1`, then you'd need to store it somewhere initially. Either in a const variable or similar.

Comment: so make another div of it and reference that?

Comment: e.g.: `const originContent = tt1.innerHTML;` and change t1 listener to `tt1.innerHTML = originContent;`

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to show element like:

```
const t1 = document.querySelector('.trigger1');
const t2 = document.querySelector('.trigger2');
const t3 = document.querySelector('.trigger3');

// text container
const tt1 = document.querySelector('.tab_text');
const tt2 = document.querySelector('.tab_text2');
const tt3 = document.querySelector('.tab_text3');

t1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    tt1.style.display = "block";
    tt2.style.display = "none";
    tt3.style.display = "none";
})

t2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    tt1.style.display = "none";
    tt2.style.display = "block";
    tt3.style.display = "none";
})

t3.addEventListener('click', function () {
    tt1.style.display = "none";
    tt2.style.display = "none";
    tt3.style.display = "block";
})
```